# How to do search and pagination on same page in CakePHP 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm struggling to doing search and putting result on same page with pagination in CakePHP 3.x.

Firstly I tried a technique but it is not giving desired result. In that, I made  few search fields on "page 1"  and after click on "search"  I do ajax call to fetch result from function "page 2" and load result on "page 1" but after clicking on next it redirects me to "page 2" while I want to stay on "page 1".

In other technique I'm thinking to use ajax call to load "JSON" data on same page but the problem is "I have no idea and could not find form internet" how to do pagination with Json data.

Anyone of you have a better idea to do search and load data on same page with pagination.

Comment: You want to implement PRG, post-redirect-get and read the CakePHP manual about JSON views. This should give you more than enough key words to educate yourself based on resources you'll find via Google and the official documentation. And *after* you did that, check https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search

Comment: @burzum I know about post-redirect-get, the thing is I don't want to redirect page otherwise it's quit easy. I just want to keep user on same page and putting result on same page while he's doing search

Comment: @burzum the first technique I tried is here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018942/how-to-deal-with-ajax-pagination-on-other-page-which-is-using-ajax-call-to-load

Comment: actually the paginated links have url of other page " page 2" that's why those redirect to another page on click. how can i use ajax call to get result and keep them on same page.

Comment: So let me try to establish what it is you want. You want to to have a page where it shows the search content, then when the person clicks "Next" on the pagination, it flushes the current content of the search and displays the second page of the search results without ever leaving the page. Correct?

Comment: yes,  I need a page where search forum is given and when user will do search, it should bring the result on same page with pagination. @spencdev